# c# socket send details

Tags: c#, file, sockets

im trying to send file over a socket,but i would like also to send the file's name for example.

this is the send code:

```
        int count = 0;
    int size;
    private int SendVarData(Socket s, byte[] data)
    {
        total = 0;
        int size = data.Length;
        int dataleft = size;
        int sent;


        datasize = BitConverter.GetBytes(size);
        sent = s.Send(datasize);


        sent = s.Send(data, total, dataleft, SocketFlags.None);
        total += sent;
        dataleft -= sent;
        //  MessageBox.Show("D");

        return total;
    }
```

**this is the call**

```
       byte[] arr = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
        SendVarData(sc, arr);//sc is a socket ofcourse.
```

i would like to send also the file name as i said. should i send it once before the file send itself? or there's another efficient way to send both?

this is the receive code:

```
private byte[] ReceiveVarData(Socket s)
    {
        int total = 0;
        int recv;
        byte[] datasize = new byte[4];

        recv = s.Receive(datasize, 0, 4, 0);
        size = BitConverter.ToInt32(datasize, 0);
        int dataleft = size;
        //MessageBox.Show(size.ToString());
        byte[] data = new byte[size];


        while (total < size)
        {
            recv = s.Receive(data, total, dataleft, 0);
            if (recv == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            total += recv;
            dataleft -= recv;
        }
        return data;
    }
```

any help would be apperciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it matters whether you send it before or after the file. You need a protocol, e.g., first send length of file name, then file name, then length of file and file itself, or other way around. On the receiving side you can differentiate the messages now-because you know length of each chunk (assuming the two length variables are always 4 byte integers say).

Comment: thank you very much but i would like not to use networkstreams in my project(personal reason it realy doesnt matter why :D) but if i would like to send a name of the file,and to read it (only the name ) in the first time. i should also create a buffer which long as the name.lenth. how can i know the length of the file name? do i have to send it also before sending **the file name**? @Giorgi

Comment: @itapi:yes, send it along too

Comment: one last question,now i need to send the length of the filename as you said. how may i know the length of the length of the file name? i mean if its 12 characters so 12 is actually 2 length string. how can i know in the other side what's the length and how much to read in this line?                 ` recv = s.Receive(datasize, 0, XXX, 0);`

Comment: @itapi:Say length is 12 bytes(mind encodings e.g. UTF8 etc. - you must convert your string to bytes based on some encoding on which length of the string will depend). First you send length. This length is fixed right? Say you send length as integer. On server side you receive 4 bytes which store length(4 bytes needed to represent integer). Now you receive *exactly* that many bytes from client. You know 12 bytes should follow. Read more [here](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/advanced.html#sonofdataencap)